# how to transform/flatten R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with names for row identity and dates as column identity.

```
df <- data.frame(`20171007` = c(8, 4),
                 `20171014` = c(9, 7),
                 row.names = c("Kohl", "Travis"))
```

What I want is a data structure with three columns, where the identity is actually data.

```
Date (get from column identity)
Name (get from row identity)
Value (get from df[r,c])
```

In this particular case I would end up with 4 rows, one for each value. How do I go about flattening my `df` into that structure?

Comment: How to write a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5965451/3651529

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "Name") %>%      # tibble
  gather(Date, Value, -Name) %>%            # tidyr
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "X%Y%m%d"))   # dplyr
```

**Result:**

```
    Name       Date Value
1   Kohl 2017-10-07     8
2 Travis 2017-10-07     4
3   Kohl 2017-10-14     9
4 Travis 2017-10-14     7
```

**Data:**

```
df = data.frame(`20171007` = c(8, 4),
                `20171014` = c(9, 7),
                row.names = c("Kohl", "Travis"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple one-liner is to transpose the `df` and then `melt` (from `reshape2`)

```
melt(t(df), value.name = "Value", varnames = c("Date", "Name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is use something similar to below. One note of caution, it is not generally good practice to have a numeric as a column name. This will lead to compatibility issues with other functions.

```
df = data.frame(`20171007` = c(8,4), 
            `20171014` = c(9, 7))
row.names(df) = c('Kohl', 'Travis')
```

Create column with row names

```
df$names <- row.names(df)
```

Use the package `tidyr` to reshape data

**EDIT - @useR**

```
df %>% 
  gather(date, value, -names)
```

Comment: This doesn't give the desired result, since your `names` is also gathered. You need to exclude `name` from `gather` like `df %>% gather(date, value, -name)` from my answer

Comment: Right you are. Thanks for the information. I like your much better anyways (without the gaff).